# VS2017 ESLint does not analyze large files

Tags: visual-studio-2017, eslint

I'm using ESLint to analyze my files in Visual Studio 2017.
It seemed like there was some mistake in the configuration because nothing seemed to work, but I later made some interesting finds:

- Small files will be analyzed
- Large files will not be analyzed (1500 rows seem to be enough, I don't have a more accurate figure - not so large after all)
- Editing a large file so that it becomes small, and then saving, makes no difference. The file is still not analyzed.
- Editing a small file so that it becomes large, and then saving, will analyze the now large file.

So it would seem like this depends on how big the file is the moment I load the solution/open VS. I did not double check if unloading and reloading the solution has the same effect as closing and reopening it.

If a previously small file gets edited to be large, then VS is reopened, the file will now not be analyzed - the reverse is valid for files large to small.

If I open cmd in any of the project's folder and run 'eslint **' all the files will get analyzed.

So my questions are:

- is there a config to be set somewhere that could be the cause of this?
- does a workaround come to mind? I tought I could maybe keep an empty js file and work into it as long as I want to lint and then copy to the definitive file. Or maybe I could setup Gulp to run ESLint? Or at the very least manually run it from cmd.

Some closing info: before asking I tried some things I found only, like running npm install eslint in [vsfolder]/Web/Extensions

I only have one .eslintrc and it's the local one created by Visual Studio, located in C:/Users/myuser/

EDIT: this is a VS2017 bug. 35kb is the size limit, it seems to be unconfigurable and undocumented.

Comment: Try using [VisualLinter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JeanAlexanderWoldner.VisualLinter) extension, works with latest versions of ESLint and replaces built-in ESLint in VS2017 which seems to be very outdated.